# Jupyter/ipython notebook has an error, can not uninstall it

Tags: python, kernel, ipython, uninstallation, jupyter-notebook

First of all, I am a linux beginner. I installed jupyter and anaconda on my Ubuntu 16.04. When running the notebook, kernel was always dead. So I deleted both, for reinstalling later. But I just can not get rid of some jupyter files, here a short list:

```
nestor@nestor-VPCEH1M1E:~$ locate jupyter
/home/nestor/.jupyter
/home/nestor/.jupyter/migrated
/usr/local/bin/jupyter
/usr/local/bin/jupyter-kernelspec
/usr/local/bin/jupyter-migrate
/usr/local/bin/jupyter-nbconvert
/usr/local/bin/jupyter-nbextension
/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook
/usr/local/bin/jupyter-qtconsole
/usr/local/bin/jupyter-serverextension
/usr/local/bin/jupyter-troubleshoot
/usr/local/bin/jupyter-trust
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyter_core-4.2.0-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyter_core-4.2.0-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyter_core-4.2.0-py2.7.egg/jupyter.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyter_core-4.2.0-py2.7.egg/jupyter.pyc
...
```

and there are around 100 more files in the directory `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyter_core-4.2.0-py2.7.egg/` . And this files are indeed there, I have updated the database with `sudo updatedb` and they are still being displayed after running `locate jupyter`. Furthermore, the command `jupyter notebook` still starts a notebook in my browser, with a still dead kernel.

I am afraid to continue removing these files, because they are protected and I don't know how this will affect my computer. Can anybody help me deleting the rest of jupyter, for reinstalling it again?
And I am also wondering what the cause of the always dead kernel was? The file-names here are refering to python2.7, but the jupyter notebook in my browser creates python3 files. Could this be the reason?

Thanks for your help, I need python for doing simulations for my final thesis!

Comment: You could try `sudo pip uninstall jupyter_core notebook qtconsole jupyter_client (...)`. Unfortunately, Jupyter is made of quite a lot of packages and pip doesn't have a way to remove them all as one. It shouldn't be a problem to delete all of those files and install Jupyter again using Anaconda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers! It worked out eventually when after the installation of Anaconda the script asked me if I want to append the startup commands to my .bashrc file and I selected "yes". I was sure I have done it after the previous installations, too, but it worked after the n-th installation. Or maybe it was just some restart-the-computer issue that solved my problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new env in conda and install it there without caring about previous installation

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on Mac - couldn't uninstall Jupyter. Thomas K comment to original post helped me.

```
sudo pip uninstall jupyter_core notebook qtconsole jupyter_client
```